# Strange response from 'git push' command

Tags: git, github, push, git-push

I'm using GIT bash, and anytime I push a commit the command runs, and actually works just fine, but the first two lines of the response always begin with:

```
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
```

Again, everything makes it to Github just fine, but I'm just wondering if there's something I need to be worried about behind the scenes. Any help is appreciated!

If needed, the full response looks like this:

```
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 1.19 KiB | 303.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/acumulus8/Portfolio.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

Comment: Does your repo have any pre commit hooks?

Comment: not sure what hooks are...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on windows, try upgrading your `GCM` version to `1.14.0`

https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.14.0